# The relationship between hair growth and caffeine ..?

Tags: caffeine, health, beans

Does caffeine really enhance hair growth and keep the hair healthy? was it proven?

Comment: Our help says: 
"Coffee Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people interested in all aspects of producing and consuming coffee." - Could you please clarify how this is on topic? Are you asking about drinking coffe and influence on hair? The only connection between caffeine and hair is the addition of caffeine to some hair products, and this would be better on Health SE or even Sceptics SE, imho.

Comment: I had to vote-to-close as dupe and for being off-topic. If you have a specific citation that you'd like to provide, or want to change the question, please do so!